# Fitting required curve through data points

Tags: matlab, plot, trigonometry

I have set of points as shown in the image below
[image]

The blue points represent a sinusoidal curve of decreasing amplitude.These are the only points I have.How will I plot the curve(decreasing amplitude sin curve) which exactly traces these points.I tried a sinusoidal fit but it does not work.

I have edited to add the entire code below

```
clc;clear all;
v = 1;t = 14.14;
for ink = 0:1:30
Wi = [0,0];Wf = [100,100];
line([0,100],[0,100],'color','g');

if(ink == 0)
uav_st = [10,0];
plot(uav_st(1,1),uav_st(1,2),'-x','MarkerSize',5);
chi = 0;
end

Ru = sqrt( ((Wi(1,1) - uav_st(1,1))^2)  + ((Wi(1,2) - uav_st(1,2))^2)  );
theta = atan2(Wf(1,2) - Wi(1,2) , Wf(1,1) - Wi(1,1));
theta_u = atan2(uav_st(1,2) - Wi(1,2),uav_st(1,1) - Wi(1,1));
beta = theta - theta_u;
R = sqrt(Ru^2 - (Ru*sin(beta))^2);
x_t = (R+ink)*cos(theta);
y_t = (R+ink)*sin(theta);
chi_d = (atan2(y_t - uav_st(1,2),x_t - uav_st(1,1)));
chi_r = chi_d*180/pi;
x_dot =(v*cos(chi_d));
y_dot =(v*sin(chi_d));
x_uav = x_dot*t+uav_st(1,1);
y_uav = y_dot*t+uav_st(1,2);
plot(x_uav,y_uav,'-x','MarkerSize',5);
%comet(x_uav,y_uav);
axis([0 100 0 100]);
axis('square');
uav_st(1,1) = x_uav;uav_st(1,2) = y_uav;
chi = chi_d;
pause(0.2);
hold on 
X_UAV(ink+1,1) = x_uav;
Y_UAV(ink+1,1) = y_uav;

end

ft=fittype('sin1');
cf=fit(X_UAV,Y_UAV,ft);
plot(cf);
```

The last three lines of the above curve give the sinusoidal fit.You can run it in your machine to see what happens exactly.Here is what the sinusoidal fit gives(the red line which is very close to the green line)
[image]

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you provide examples of points and some matlab code you tried?

Comment: If you run the code you will find that the fit is close to the green line.But what I want is the actual sinusoidal curve.

Comment: Don't have matlab handy but will polyfit/polyval give what you're looking for? using these built in functions allows you to choose the order for the fit.

Comment: Your problem seems to be a problem of modelisation. You want to find a "sinusoidal curve of decreasing amplitude". I don't see a sinusoid as it seems to be align on the line `y=x` and not the x-axis. So try other models ... maybe something like `x+a*sin(b*x+c)/x`?